# Show image using file_get_contents in a popup window

Tags: view, layout

I am trying to show an image in a popup window using file_get_contents function and an echo statement.

Here is the code I have in the first view

```
<a href='javascript:window.open("index.php?option=com_jsmdownload&view=request&tmpl=component&layout=showimage&img=icon-36-ldpi.png", "Image View", "toolbar=no, location=no, width=400, height=400")'>Click</a>
```

Below is the code in my second layout inside the same view

```
$image = JURI::base().DS.'files'.DS.'images'.DS.'icon.png';
//echo $image;
$content = file_get_contents($image); 
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $content; exit();
```

When I click the 'Click' anchor in the first view it opens the popup window and it shows garbage inside.

[image]

The image path is correct and if I brows the image path in an another browser URL it shows the image.

Not sure what I am missing.  Can someone please help on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with Jeremy, you could simply use an `<img>` tag and insert the filename using PHP.

However, if for some reason you want to read the file using PHP, try using `readfile()`. In addition, you can use **[getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)** to get the correct mime type and insert it dynamically. That way you're not limited to using one file type:

```
$image = JURI::base().DS.'files'.DS.'images'.DS.'icon.png';
$imginfo = getimagesize($image);
header("Content-type: ".$imginfo['mime']);
readfile($image);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It still shows garbage characters on the screen. Updated my question with the output screenshot.  Any advice on this?

Comment: Can you try the code in a standalone PHP file? If it works, then start adding it partially into your component, first without the popup, until you get a clue as to where it stops working.

Comment: There was an empty line which causes the headache.  It works fine after removing empty lines.  Also `exit` is mandatory after `readfile($image)`.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you solved it. And welcome to Joomla StackExchange!

Comment: @Malaiselvan: I'd be interested in knowing a little more about the context that you're working in. I did a quick test with the code that johanpw wrote, and it works basically as written. The exit() is not something that should ever be needed or used in production code, as that stops all execution of scripts for the current user. If things aren't working for you unless you use exit(), then something else is wrong with the surrounding code that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @JeremyProffitt -I have 2 layouts in a same view.  In the first view a series of anchor tags will be shown and for each anchor an image is tagged. Clicking the anchor should show the image in the second layout in a popup. No other code is required inside the second layout after the readfile command.  I understand the exit will stop the code but since it is inside the popup and shown on an anchor link I believe it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

Setting the header and trying to process the image directly is really unnecessary. This will produce the result you're looking for:

Your second code block should be as follows

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$layout = $input->get('layout');
If (isset($layout) && $layout == 'show image') {
$image = JURI::base().'files/images/icon.png';
printf('<img src="%s" />', $images);
```

}

Comment: I understand the img tag will work. But due to some security reason I shouldn't go with that approach. That's the reason trying with get file contents.

Comment: Makes sense. The answer given by @johanpw will definitely work.